# Animate Remove SwiftUI View Glitches

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to slide in a view over the bottom, to display a small note, and then slide off after a few seconds..

slide in is working fine, but when it slides out, it glitches:

```
   if let err = error {
        ErrorView(err)
            .animation(.spring())
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            .onAppear(perform: errorAppeared)
    }
```

When there is an error, it transitions just fine, but when there isn't, instead of sliding down or inversing, it just pops off the view

I am calling this function to clear the view:

```
private func clearError() {
    withAnimation {
        self.error = nil
    }
}
```

none of the existing questions helped, I tried to do things in the 'onReceive' function and about every other answer I could find, most say it should just work, or to use animation, or transition, I believe I've tried most combinations and at this point am quite stuck

Answer (score 1):

I assume the animation is just in wrong place - put it for container holding condition and link it to dependent state variable, like below

```
VStack {   // << can be as-is, only for condition
   if let err = error {
        ErrorView(err)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            .onAppear(perform: errorAppeared)
    }
}
.animation(.spring(), value: error)  // << here !!
```

and then just activate in regular way

```
private func clearError() {
   self.error = nil
}
```

Comment: still not working for me somehow.. I had to setup a bool or something equatable to trigger it and moved my error so it wasn't observed state..

Comment: oh also, in another test view I was able to get it working without putting it outside of the view stack, I think it might be like an order of things on my chain  or sth

Comment: Then please provide reproducible example

Comment: it's sort of all baked into an api thing for me to make it small, I'll see if I can trim it down later, sorry, was a bit frustrated with it and needed to shelve it for progress momentarily